# I want to return a JSON object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array.

```
numbers = ["1","2"]
```

I want to convert this array into the following object

```
numberList = {"1" : [], "2" : []}
```

I tried like following. but it does not work. I want to pass the number as a variable.

```
numbers.map( function(number) {
      return {number : []};
  })
```

Comment: reduce, not map

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: numbers.map( function(number) {
      return {[number] : []};
  })

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could map entries and build an object from it.

```js
const
    numbers = ["1", "2"],
    object = Object.fromEntries(numbers.map(key => [key, []]));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think i would simply loop it and build the object

```
let numbers = ["1","2"];
let newObject = {};

for(let i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    newObject[numbers[i]] = [];
}

console.log(newObject);
```

The other answers here provide cleaner methods in my opinion. This is pretty old school.

Comment: Or even `for (const number of numbers) { newObject[number] = []; }` *(And agreed on the loop. :-) Or `fromEntries` as Nina shows.)*

Comment: I am realizing with all these answers there are cleaner ways to do this.

Comment: Oh, a simple loop is nice, clean, clear, and efficient IMHO. I certainly wouldn't use `reduce`. Overcomplicated and easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take your array and convert it into an object. To do that you want to use reduce.

```js
numbers = ["1","2"]

var result = numbers.reduce( function (o, n) {
  o[n] = [];
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```